# Can't load file or assembly X when switching computers

Tags: .net, xamarin-studio

I'm using Xamarin.Studio on 2 machines Windows and Mac.

I keep getting these annoying random errors every time I make a change on one platform then switch to working on the other platform. That is, I have a PC running Windows where I do some development then sometimes I develop on my Mac. I use Git.

I have two projects. A library project and a unit test project. These are the current dependencies:

Library project:

```
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="portable-net45+win+wpa81+wp80+MonoAndroid10+xamarinios10+MonoTouch10" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl" version="1.1.10" targetFramework="portable-net45+win+wpa81+wp80+MonoAndroid10+xamarinios10+MonoTouch10" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl.Build" version="1.0.21" targetFramework="portable-net45+win+wpa81+wp80+MonoAndroid10+xamarinios10+MonoTouch10" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Net.Http" version="2.2.29" targetFramework="portable-net45+win+wpa81+wp80+MonoAndroid10+xamarinios10+MonoTouch10" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="7.0.1" targetFramework="portable-net45+win+wpa81+wp80+MonoTouch10+MonoAndroid10+xamarinmac20+xamarinios10" />
```

Testing project:

```
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl" version="1.1.10" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Bcl.Build" version="1.0.21" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Net.Http" version="2.2.29" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="7.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="NUnit" version="2.6.3" targetFramework="net45" />
```

The first problem I had was when I switched from Mac to Windows and the tests wouldn't run. I finally realise that I had to:

- Reinstall Json package in the library project
- Add 5 packages to the test porject (the first 5 in the previous list)
- Add a redirection in app.config to both projects for Json:

  ```
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-7.0.0.0" newVersion="7.0.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </assemblyBinding>
  ```

Keep in mind that this problem didn't surface until I switched to Windows.. it was compiling and running just fine on Mac.

Now, I switched back to my Mac, and yet again another random bizarre problem..

```
SetUp : System.IO.FileNotFoundException : Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http, Version=1.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies.
```

I just can't figure out why on earth do these problems only happen when I switch to another PC. This has to be some problem with the cache system of botch .Net and Mono

My question is:

- How to avoid this type of problem (clean cache?)
- How to fix this particular error?

Comment: You probably need redirect for `System.Net.Http` too... And find out what brings that unexpected dependency - usually it happens when you have 2 versions and one override another in bin folder depending on build order. Side note: `id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="8.0.1" ` - should not redirection be to version `8.0.0.0`?

Comment: I don't even see any dll in the output bin folder called System.Net.Http. I do have it in the library project, though, just not the testing one... even though it has all the packages the library project has.

Comment: See my answer please

Answer (score 2):

I managed to solve this particular error by telling Xamarin.Studio to do a "Local Copy" on System.Net.Http:

- I noticed that System.Net.Htpp.dll is not even in the bin folder (for the test project)
- I can see the project is referencing it
- Right click -> Properties
- Check "Local Copy" (Copies the referenced assembly to the output folder, default no)
- Now I can see the dll in bin
- The test project runs fine now in the test pad

This is such bizarre and time-wasting behaviour it's truly frustrating and not fun to fix.